# Nav-pills not working as expected in a panel-heading

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, tabs, xpages, panel

I have added a nav-pill to the panel-heading and it is not working as expected. The onclick event fires correctly and switches the displayed panel correctly but the selected tab is not highlited. If I move the container-fluid out side the panel-heading it selects the tab when clicked.
I like  the effect I get by using the bootstrap panel and panel-heading but would be nice if the tab could be selected when clicked.

any ideas???

```
<xp:panel id="panelMain">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-4">
                            <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                                <li role="presentation">
                                    <xp:link id="header" text="Header">
                                        <xp:this.attrs>
                                            <xp:attr name="data-toggle" value="tab">
                                            </xp:attr>
                                        </xp:this.attrs>
                                        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
                                            refreshMode="partial" refreshId="panelMain">
                                            <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:viewScope.vsShowPanel = "Header"}]]></xp:this.action>
                                        </xp:eventHandler>
                                    </xp:link>
                                </li><!-- li role= -->
                                <li role="presentation">
                                    <xp:link id="history" text="History">
                                        <xp:this.attrs>
                                            <xp:attr name="data-toggle" value="tab">
                                            </xp:attr>
                                        </xp:this.attrs>
                                        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
                                            refreshMode="partial" refreshId="panelMain">
                                            <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:viewScope.vsShowPanel = "History"}]]></xp:this.action>
                                        </xp:eventHandler>
                                    </xp:link>
                                </li><!-- li role= -->
                            </ul><!-- class nav -->
                        </div><!-- col -->
                    </div><!-- main row -->
                </div><!-- container-fluid -->
        </div><!-- panel-heading -->
        <div class="panel-body">
            <xp:panel id="panelHeader">
            Header Panel
                <xp:this.style><![CDATA[#{javascript:if (!viewScope.containsKey("vsShowPanel")){
    viewScope.vsShowPanel = "Header";
}
var showPanel:String = viewScope.vsShowPanel;
(showPanel == "Header" ) ? "" : "display:none"}]]></xp:this.style>
            </xp:panel> <!-- panelHeader -->
            <xp:panel id="panelHistory">
                History panel
                <xp:this.style><![CDATA[#{javascript:(viewScope.vsShowPanel == "History") ? "" : "display:none"}]]></xp:this.style>
            </xp:panel><!-- panelHistory -->
        </div><!-- panel-body -->
    </div><!-- class=panel -->
</xp:panel><!-- panelMain -->
```

Answer (score 0):

If you refresh the panel/div that contains the Nav then the highlite  on the pill is lost. In the code below I moved the nav out of the panel header and the high lite works as expected. Not quite what I wanted but it works. I need to remember "don't do a refresh on the Nav"

```
<xp:panel id="panelNav">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-4">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                    <li role="presentation">
                        <xp:link id="header" text="Header">
                            <xp:this.attrs>
                                <xp:attr name="data-toggle" value="tab">
                                </xp:attr>
                            </xp:this.attrs>
                            <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
                                refreshMode="partial" refreshId="panelMain">
                                <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:viewScope.vsShowPanel = "Header"}]]></xp:this.action>
                            </xp:eventHandler>
                        </xp:link>
                    </li><!-- li role= -->
                    <li role="presentation">
                        <xp:link id="history" text="History">
                            <xp:this.attrs>
                                <xp:attr name="data-toggle" value="tab">
                                </xp:attr>
                            </xp:this.attrs>
                            <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
                                refreshMode="partial" refreshId="panelMain">
                                <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:viewScope.vsShowPanel = "History"}]]></xp:this.action>
                            </xp:eventHandler>
                        </xp:link>
                    </li><!-- li role= -->
                </ul><!-- class nav -->
            </div><!-- col -->
        </div><!-- main row -->
    </div><!-- container-fluid -->
</xp:panel>
<xp:panel id="panelMain">
    <div class="panel panel-default">

        <div class="panel-body">
            <xp:panel id="panelHeader">
                Header Panel
                <xp:this.style><![CDATA[#{javascript:if (!viewScope.containsKey("vsShowPanel")){
    viewScope.vsShowPanel = "Header";
}
var showPanel:String = viewScope.vsShowPanel;
(showPanel == "Header" ) ? "" : "display:none"}]]></xp:this.style>
            </xp:panel> <!-- panelHeader -->
            <xp:panel id="panelHistory">
                History panel
                <xp:this.style><![CDATA[#{javascript:(viewScope.vsShowPanel == "History") ? "" : "display:none"}]]></xp:this.style>
            </xp:panel><!-- panelHistory -->
        </div><!-- panel-body -->
    </div><!-- class=panel -->
</xp:panel><!-- panelMain -->
```